# Legend including Greek letters can not be written inside ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

The graph I plotted in ggplot looks like this:

The legend includes greek letter. Currently the legend is outside the graph. I want to move the legend inside the graph. How can I do that. The code:

```
p + theme(legend.position=c(1,7))
```

does not work. In fact it vanishes the whole legend.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Note that `opts` in the linked answer has been deprecated. Use `theme` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Their values should be between 0 and 1. c(0,0) corresponds to the “bottom left” and c(1,1) corresponds to the “top right” position.

```
p + theme(legend.position=c(0.8,0.8))
```

Comment: @ tatxif That was a typo. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Geotas see my edit.

Comment: Thanks . it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the command. Also, legend.position uses values between 0 and 1 (see [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/)). Try:

```
p + theme(legend.position = c(0.8,0.8))
```

Comment: @ Mikko Thank you. it worked.

Comment: You might want to accept the answer in that case.